# Error Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I have installed `Android SDK` and it is working OK, except: for additional items, 
e.g. **Google USB driver**

I get the error:

> File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\usb_driver_r07-windows.zip (Access is denied).

The folder ...temp is there but empty.

What is happening?

Comment: Run SDK Manager as Administrator. Don't open Android Studio or Eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

Do not use SDK Manager via Eclipse. You can find it from the Start menu and right click on it and choose "Run As Administrator".

Comment: And if you're running in Linux, you should ensure you are the owner of those folders (Android Dev Tool, SDK, or Android Studio), or you have the "write" permission on those folders.

Answer (score 5):

This issue will be resolved by running your IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio) as "Run as administrator".

OR

Set your app ICON to run application always as Administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right click, select Run as Administrator. It should not cause any issue now and installation should work fine. See [Issue #72982 SDK Manager cannot update when installed in C:\Program Files (x86), unless run as Administrator.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=72982)

Answer (score 1):

I think you must put the android SDK file in a path without spaces and because eclipse can't read the file

try it and give me your feedback....

Comment: 1. I used Android SDK directly, NOT via Eclipse.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: To launch the SDK Manager, right-click the exec and click 'run as administrator'. Solution given to a previous similar question - see the Related: 'Android SDK Manager Not Installing Components'. I am grateful to the author, William Tate.